# How to get amazon affiliate product Url programatically

Tags: amazon-web-services

I need to get Amazon product affiliate Url programatically without logging in to 
affiliate-program.amazon.com.

I know how to get it manually.
Log into Associates
Go to Product Linking -> Product Links

### Search for the product and get the Text Link

I want the same programatically just by using ASIN, access key, amazon secret key,
and my associate tag.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 8):

You can use open-source libraries like [Affiliate JS](https://affiliate.js.org/) to automatically add the affiliation tags to links on your website.

```
<script data-aff="amazon.com, www.amazon.com : tag = MY-AMAZON-TAG" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/affiliate@1.2/dist/affiliate.js" async id="aff-js"></script>
```

Just simply replace `MY-AMAZON-TAG` with the tag that you made in Amazon (that probably looks like `my-tag-20`) and add the HTML right above the `</head>`. If you want to affiliate your URLs manually, simply add `?tag=my-tag` to the end.

```
Before: https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0042TVKZY/
After: https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0042TVKZY/?tag=MY-AMAZON-TAG

Before: https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0042TVKZY/ref=longvndjks?nsjklasd=nkdnc
After: https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0042TVKZY/?tag=MY-AMAZON-TAG
```

Comment: But the actual affiliate links which we generate has `linkid` and `linkCode` in queryparams along with the tag

Comment: Are you sure this will be considered as a valid affiliate link? @Russell

Comment: @MuraliK I believe so. Read through [this article](https://amazon-affiliate.eu/en/how-to-add-amazon-affiliate-links/) from an Amazon blog which documents this method. I believe `linkid` and `linkCode` are either for internal purposes for Amazon, or to attribute sales by a certain link (e.g. this link on the sidebar works better than a link in the footer).

Comment: Can someone confirm this works? I think it's tracking clicks to my account, but not conversions.

Comment: @Tahlor It seems like that to me too, can anyone confirm or any other solution?

Comment: seem it doesn't work anymore. Do we have a workaround?

Answer (score 7):

Okay, so I just went down this rabbit hole looking at the Amazon Product Advertising API 5, 3rd party libraries & repos thinking that I needed to generate special parameters to make the attribution valid, but then stumbled upon this **much** simpler strategy: https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/help/node/topic/GP38PJ6EUR6PFBEC

Straight from Amazon as of July 7, 2023:

> While we suggest that you use our Build Links tools to ensure that you
> have a properly formatted link and to ensure that you qualify for the
> direct link bonus, we have received a lot of requests for a simple
> text link. So if you need to build a simple text link to a specific
> item on Amazon.com, here is the link format you need to use:
>
> http://www.amazon.com/dp/ASIN/ref=nosim?tag=YOURASSOCIATEID This link
> format qualifies for the direct link bonus.
>
> Just replace ASIN and YOURASSOCIATEID with the respective details:
>
> ASIN: ASIN is the 10-digit code that Amazon uses to denote specific
> products. It is short for "Amazon.com Standard Item Number."
>
> YOURASSOCIATEID: YOURASSOCIATEID is the unique ID that is used to identify your Associates account, automatically generated when you apply for the Associates Programme.

So yeah, if all you need is to programmatically generate the affiliate link this still works.

Comment: I just filled out a Contact Us email to Amazon Affilliates because I noticed the (otherwise very helpful) page that you have quoted here is prefacing their URLs with the outdated http:// protocol rather than the appropriate/secure protocol https://

Comment: Does it work for other countries like Canada or UK? The documentation doesn't mention it.

Comment: I've tested this type of link with Amazon DE and the purchase was commissioned correctly, can't say yet exactly for other regions, but if I get any more confirmations I'll add them here.

Answer (score 0):

I am looking for the same thing. From my searches, it looks like you can use the Product Advertising API by Amazon to generate the links.